# google plus button '>9999' +1's

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

We have the +1 Button on our website which is available in different languages.
The problem is that in every language the button shows '>9999' +1's (or something similar) and not the real amount of +1's like on the English one. The English button says 31k and this is what I want in the other languages, too.

Why does the English one shows the actual amount and in every other language not? Is there a way to display the actual number of +1's?

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine it has something to do with the suffix `k`. It stands for `kilo` and roughly means "thousand", I would imagine that not all languages utilize that as a suffix. So 31k wouldn't mean anything to them, whereas >9999 does at least mean something.

Comment: Some languages actually have the k suffix, too. But the button shows '>9999'. And many languages have their own suffix, like in Germany 'tsd'. The Facebook-Likebutton e.g. shows the languages correspondent suffix.
And in some languages it show 'many'. Very precise ...